# Display all validation messages inline at once onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I would like JavaScript to display all the validation messages at once when the submit button is clicked.

`Customer Name: TextBox: *Customer Name must not be blank
 Address      : TextBox: *Address must not be blank
 City         : TextBox:  *City must not be blank`

But it displays only one message at a time, every time the submit button is clicked.

This is my code.

```
<form  method="post" name="customer" action="newcustcheck.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" >
    <table width="200">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>Customer Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message" ></td>

        </tr><tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message1"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message2"></td>
        </tr>
```

JavaScript

```
 function Validate(){
var x=document.forms["customer"]["name"].value;
var y=document.forms["customer"]["address"].value;
var z=document.forms["customer"]["city"].value;

if(x==null || x==""){
    document.getElementById('message').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="Customer Name must not be blank";
    return false;

}
else{
    document.getElementById('message').style.visibility="hidden";

    }
//T8
if(y==null || y==""){
    document.getElementById('message1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML="Address Field must not be blank";
    return false;
}
else{
    document.getElementById('message1').style.visibility="hidden";
    }

//T12
if(z==null || z==""){
    document.getElementById('message2').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML="City Field must not be blank";
    return false;
}
else{
    document.getElementById('message2').style.visibility="hidden";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the `validate` function as soon as you find first `invalid` input, you should keep looking instead and return only after every input field is validated.

```js
function Validate(){

var x=document.forms["customer"]["name"].value;
var y=document.forms["customer"]["address"].value;
var z=document.forms["customer"]["city"].value;
var isValid = true;

if(x==null || x==""){
    document.getElementById('message').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="Customer Name must not be blank";
    isValid =  false;

}
else{
    document.getElementById('message').style.visibility="hidden";

    }
//T8
if(y==null || y==""){
    document.getElementById('message1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML="Address Field must not be blank";
    isValid =  false;
}
else{
    document.getElementById('message1').style.visibility="hidden";
    }

//T12
if(z==null || z==""){
    document.getElementById('message2').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML="City Field must not be blank";
    isValid =  false;
}
else{
    document.getElementById('message2').style.visibility="hidden";
    }
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<form  method="post" name="customer" action="newcustcheck.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" >
    <table width="200">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>Customer Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message" ></td>

        </tr><tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message1"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><div class="message">*</div>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" ></td>
            <td> <label class="message" id="message2"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  <input type=submit />
      </form>
```